# Make content min-height fill the screen

Tags: html, css

As an example, I've made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L7mwpzux/3/

How do I make the div `.container` minimally fill the screen?
So when there is almost no content, it still fills the screen.

It's for a page that is shown when the checkout cart is empty. The content is too thin, so the screen is not fully filled with content.

---

P.s. I am not looking for an answer that assumes that the header or footer has a static height. I want to be able to use it also in situations where the height of the header or footer is variable.

Also, I would love a CSS solution, so no JavaScript or jQuery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `calc()` and set `100vh - height of header`, also add `box-sizing: border-box` to keep padding inside.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>

<div class="container">
  small text
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Other approach is to use `Flexbox` and set `display: flex` on body which is parent element in this case with `min-height: 100vh` and then just set `flex: 1` on `.container` so it takes rest of free height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>

<div class="container">
  small text
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: I know, but the problem is, is that the header can be variable in height :/ same for the footer

Comment: The flexbox solution resulted in the page made smaller in width, is it supposed to go that way?

Comment: I cannot share screenshots, because I am doing an internship at a company. What I mean, is that the page just shrinked, literally.

Comment: Probably cos `border-box` is not implemented on your page. It tells the browser to include all padding and border with the height/width of all elements.

Comment: `:)` Can you recreate the problem in fiddle i cannot tell why like this, yes it could be `border-box`.

Comment: Just tried border-box, didn't work. I wil recreate the problem as good as possible. Give me 5 min :)

Comment: I have updated my fiddle. It seems a wrapper is causing some trouble. Problem is, the wrapper can't be removed, because a load of pages have this

Comment: My hero! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 400px);
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L7mwpzux/1/

Comment: My question states that I am not looking for an solution where the answer is based on the fact that the header and/or footer has a static height

Comment: Is that the only way? :/ I was hoping for a CSS solution

Comment: That's almost the same solution the other guy gave me. Same problem here, the page literally shrinked

Comment: actually we do not have the exact code or live link of your project .. so we tried to provide solution for your fiddle ..

Comment: Like I said, unfortunately I cannot share anything